# Call function on mousemove

Tags: javascript

I have a java Script function that i want to call whenever mouse moves so whats the way to call it in java script.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered Google?  http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+mouse+move+event

Comment: Are we talking about JavaScript in HTML, XML or similar DOM document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you didn't really provide an element onto which you want to attach the handler, but here's how to do it with the body element:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function move() {
alert("Your mouse moved!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onmousemove="move()">
<div>Test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to have an html element that will fire the event. For instance

```
 <div onmousemove="foo()"></div>
```

If you want it to happen all over the page I believe that putting the event on the body tag will work but I am not sure.

Here is a reference for the event http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp

Answer (score 1):

Samuel and Salty both provide a bad way of attaching event listeners! Separate your presentation from the application, please!

```
function move(){
    //do something on mouse move
}

function addEvent(elm, evType, fn, useCapture) {
    if (elm.addEventListener) {
        elm.addEventListener(evType, fn, useCapture);
        return true;
    }
    else if (elm.attachEvent) {
        var r = elm.attachEvent('on' + evType, fn);
        return r;
    }
    else {
        elm['on' + evType] = fn;
    }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    }
    else {
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}

function init(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    addEvent(body, 'mousemove', move);
}

addLoadEvent(init);
```

Thanks to Dustin Diaz for [event handling functions](http://www.dustindiaz.com/top-ten-javascript/) - or use your favourite library.