# call function on iframe mouse move

Tags: javascript

I have a function that i need to call on iframe mousemove(). But i didnt found anything like we have in body tag 
We have `<body mousemove="Function()">` Do we have anything like this for iframe??

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641053/call-function-on-mousemove ? See @David Caunt's response.

Comment: Not a dupe, `<iframe>`s are special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iframe` contains its own `document`, own `body` element etc.
Try something like this:

```
var frame = document.getElementById("yourIframeId");
// IE is special
var frameDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document;
var frameBody = frameDoc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

var testingOneTwo = function() {
    console.log("Hello, is this thing on?");
};
frameBody.onmouseover = testingOneTwo;
```

Comment: But Where I should put this code. is it put inside the iframe tag ?? or should put it inside my main page <script>tag</script>. I really confusing too much. Please can you more elaborate.

Comment: This would be in the main page, as I assumed you wanted it. You can of course just put it directly in the document that is loaded in the iframe.
Oh, remember to wait for onload (or put the `<script>` at the bottom) if you try the script, so that it can find the `<iframe>` when it runs.

Comment: Oh, if you put it in the document that is loaded in the iframe, it should be just like any other document, you should be able to do `<body onmousemove="foo()">` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `onMouseOver` or `onFocus`?

e.g.

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>  
  <script language="javascript">
  <!--
function SayHello()
{
 alert("Hi from IFrame");
}

  //-->
  </script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>
 <iframe id="myiFrame" onMouseOver="SayHello()"/>
<iframe id="myiFrame" onFocus="SayHello()"/>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```